# Помогите избавиться от повторений if в javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Есть "код":

```
if ( type == "cool" ){
    if ( skin.category == "cool" ){
        skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
    }
}
if ( type == "flags" ){
    if ( skin.category == "flags" ){
        skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
    }
}
if ( type == "elite" ){
    if ( skin.category == "elite" ){
        skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
    }
}
if ( type == "elite" ){
    if ( skin.category == "elite" ){
        skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
    }
}
if ( type == "vip" ){
    if ( skin.category == "vip" ){
        skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
    }
}
```

Выглядит очень не красиво, понимаю что можно было бы оформить лучше - но не совсем понимаю как.

Comment: Помимо свича тут еще во всех ветках действия одинаковые

Comment: @Утка, намекаешь на цикл? :-) хотя да :-) какой тут цикл - когда все нужно в одно условие впихнуть :-)

Comment: @Grundy на array.indexOf скорее

Answer (score 15, accepted):

А теперь запихнем в один if

```
const allowedTypes = [
  "cool",
  "flags",
  "elite",
  "vip"
];

if(type===skin.category && allowedTypes.indexOf(type)!==-1){
    skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
};
```

Comment: эх :-) не успел я :-) Я бы сравнение перед поиском в массиве поставил, чтобы лишний раз по нему не бегать

Comment: @Grudny, да, логично, поправил)

Comment: `allowedTypes.indexOf(type)!==-1` – а нельзя как-нибудь ещё проще проверять вхождение элемента в множество? В питоне это `type in allowedTypes`, например.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это общепринятый метод. И много лет все так делают, так что в целом такая запись jsнику понятно. В es6+ есть https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes, в jquery/undersсore/lodash (которые почти везде) есть аналоги

Comment: опечатка: *понятна

Answer (score 2):

вариант через хеш чтобы избавиться от тяжёлого `indexOf` + меньше сравнений

```
const allowedTypes = {
  "cool"  : "cool",
  "flags" : "flags",
  "elite" : "elite",
  "vip"   : "vip"
};

if (allowedTypes[type] && type === skin.category) { // edited
   skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44981/discussion-on-answer-by-ampawd-----if--javascript).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (type == "cool" && skin.category == "cool") {
    skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
}
if (type == "flags" && skin.category == "flags") {
    skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
}
if (type == "elite" && skin.category == "elite") {
    skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
}
if (type == "vip" && skin.category == "vip") {
    skinsARR[skin.categorySort] = skinsTMP;
}
```

Вот, уже в разы короче получается.

Comment: можно еще добавить || вместо кучи if